# Swinject Testing resolved service

Tags: swift, swinject

I am looking for a way to test if a service has already been resolved in the .Container scope. My application fires up a few "services" at launch and I wanted to make sure those services have been resolved without triggering them to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add logging in the factory closure to check whether the type is already resolved by the [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) container.

```
container.register(AnimalType.self) { _ in        
    // You can log here.
    print("AnimalType is being resolved to Cat.")
    return Cat()
}
.inObjectScope(.Container)
```

**EDIT**

Or you can use a flag to check in your unit test.

```
var initialized = false

container.register(AnimalType.self) { _ in        
    // You can check this parameter later in your unit test.
    initialized = true
    return Cat()
}
.inObjectScope(.Container)

XCTAssertFalse(initialized)
container.resolve(AnimalType.self)
XCTAssertTrue(initialized)
```

Comment: More so looking to do it programmatically in functional or unit tests. I would like to test if a service has been init'd.

Comment: The flag usage might not be what you want... I just noticed your requirement now.

Comment: I could use something like this for now. I was going through the source trying to figure out how to run this sort of test but Xcode and @testable were not playing too nice.